# Mongoose findOne not completing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

After trying to debug myself and searching google, my mongoose findOne is not completing! it get's to the line and just does not end, until a timeout about 2 minutes later. Here is the code in order of which it is called

----------------Routing

```
// process the signup form
app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
    failureRedirect : '/', // redirect back to the home page if there is an error
    failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
}));
```

------------ Passport Processing

```
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField    : 'email',
        passwordField    : 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass in the req from our route (lets us check if a user is logged in or not)
    },
    function (req, email, password, done) {

        // asynchronous
        process.nextTick(function () {
            //  Whether we're signing up or connecting an account, we'll need
            //  to know if the email address is in use.
            UserController.findUserByEmail(email, function (existingUser) {
                console.log(existingUser);
                // check to see if there's already a user with that email
                if (existingUser)
                    return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));

                //  If we're logged in, we're connecting a new local account.
                if (req.user) {
                    var user = req.user;
                    user.email = email;
                    user.password = encrypt.encrypt(password);
                    user.save(function (err) {
                        if (err)
                            throw err;
                        return done(null, user);
                    });
                }
                //  We're not logged in, so we're creating a brand new user.
                else {
                    console.log("there");
                    // create the user
                    User.createUser(req.body.username, email, req.body.username, password, "0", 1, function (result) {
                        return done(null, result);
                    });
                }

            });
        });

    }));
```

------------------Created Data Client (UserController)

```
exports.findUserByEmail = function(email, callback){
User.findOne({email : email}, function(err, result){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }else{
        callback(result);
    }
});
};
```

------------------User Schema

```
//user Schema
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name : String,
email  : String,
userName : String,
password : String,
IP : String,
//type of user. It can be a user admin 0, user student 1, user presentor (professor) 2, (user     guest 3) ?.
type : Number
});

//instance of my schema
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

The code runs to right before User.findOne(); and then just hangs. Adding some debugging statements shows that everything up to that method is called, but it never enters the callback. It just sits waiting.

Other queries for other schema have worked fine, and return very quickly.

I've added an error event listener for mongoose and nothing comes up.

My express server also only runs once the connection is open, so that rules that out.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated!

-Stephen

Comment: Do you call `mongoose.connect` somewhere?

Comment: Yes when starting up the server. "My express server also only runs once the connection is open, so that rules that out."

Comment: Come on SO! I know you can do it!

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a minimal example?  You've got a lot going on here.

Comment: This is the code and it's path to reproduce this "bug". Express app with the passport module. Then just drop this in. Anything less defeats the purpose of me posting here. I can fully access and query mongo just fine in a self running script. It is this route through my application that is stalling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue:

Controller File was part of another node project in the parent directory. I assume then node did not default to reading the current node process loaded modules, but tried to read the other node projects, which is not running at the time. Just moving the files into the same node project folder fixed the issue.

Comment: It seems like my suggestion "be sure your models are required before you attempt to use them" was indeed the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this same problem.  The issue for me was that I was using `mongoose.createConnection`

```
let connection = mongoose.createConnection(url, ...)
```

but then trying to use mongoose to create the model

```
let Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', yourSchema);
```

When you use createConnection you need to use that connection - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#constructing-documents.

```
let Tank = connection.model('Tank', yourSchema);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first of all, I think you're overcomplicating this. First take a look at mongoose statics: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics

Now, why do you need that separate UserController? (and seeing as this is not an MVC Controller, your naming convention is confusing -- consider renaming if you intend to keep User and UserController separate). Consider, why do you need that method at all? I mean, why not invoke User.findOne({email: "some email address"}) directly from your middleware function?

Regardless of your chosen style...

I think your issue is that you are not getting a reference to the User model in the UserController before you attempt to use it.

Add this line before your call to User.findOne in UserController:

```
var User = mongoose.model('User');
```

See if that works. (Be sure your models are required before you attempt to use them).

Comment: As for the naming conventions, the goal was for my students (who wrote it) to provide a higher level api. For a simple find, of course it was not necessary, but when aggregation and such come into play, we provided the other students who were to complete other task an easy api into the document collection. Thank you for your advice though! EDIT adding statics looks like a better convention! Thanks for the link too!